# Plan only on changed parent modules in terraform

Tags: terraform

***Given***:

Let's say there are some modules and some parent `tf` files that call their corresponding modules. For example:

```
.
├── modules
│   ├── module_1
│   ├── module_2
│   └── module_3
└── parent_modules
    ├── parent_1
    │   ├── main.tf
    │   ├── module_1.auto.tfvars
    │   └── terraform.tfstate
    ├── parent_2
    │   ├── main.tf
    │   ├── module_2.auto.tfvars
    │   └── terraform.tfstate
    └── parent_3
        ├── main.tf
        ├── module_3.auto.tfvars
        └── terraform.tfstate
```

In this example, in each `main.tf`, its child module has been called. e.g, `module_1` is called by `parent_modules/parent_1/main.tf`, etc.
Each `parent_module` has its own `statefile`. We could loop through the `parent_modules` and `plan` all the dirs without checking if its files have been changed or not.

***Question***:

Is there a way to only `plan` on changed `parent_modules` dirs.? For example, if `module_3.auto.tfvars` changed, plan would executed on `parent_modules/parent_3` dir?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. No, I wanted to plan only on the changed module.

Comment: what seems to be missing from this question is how you plan to detect such changes and run the plan. Do you mean via some CICD tool, if so which one. Are the parent modules essentially been run as root modules that are managing the state. If so running a plan would only work in the relevant dir and wouldnt plan against all of them anyway

Comment: Indeed, Terraform CLI itself will only run if you explicitly run it... it has no ability to automatically respond to changes on its own. So to achieve that would require some external system that _can_ somehow detect changes and run Terraform at the appropriate time, but I don't think there would be anything Terraform-specific about that tool; any system that can run arbitrary commands when a configuration source changes could be configured to run Terraform in that case.